# How to transfer data from Google Cloud SQL to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, bigquery-udf

I have a Google Cloud SQL database and I want to transfer the data from SQL to BigQuery on daily basis. How can I do this?
I have found some solutions for transferring data from the Google Cloud Storage bucket to BigQuery but cannot find the required solution.
Can anyone please tell me if there's any solution?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries

Comment: @FerreginaPelona gave you the right path. However, it requires a public IP on your Cloud SQL instance (no authorized network, only a public IP. It's like a public IP with firewall rule that deny all the connection. BUT, most of the time that pattern is not understood by security team and you can't have public IP on your Cloud SQL instance.). Because of that, you could have to export the data to Cloud Storage, in CSV format for instance and then load them in BigQuery.